# How can I build an automation testing framework from the scratch in Selenium with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, frameworks, webdriver

I have knowledge about selenium webdriver along with core java programming. I can write test scripts to automate the web based application / pages.

But I don't know how to make these scripts together using complete automation framework.

Can anyone please give / guide me the complete framework with source for logic scenario like how the folders structure should be, classes etc?

From there I can develop my skills....because of this reason I'm failing many job interviews and didn't get job yet :(

Thanks 
Karunagara Pandi

Comment: Use TESTNG or JUNIT

Answer (score 0):

I believe below links will help you.

https://www.guru99.com/creating-keyword-hybrid-frameworks-with-selenium.html
http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/selenium-automation-framework-example
http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/keyword-driven-framework/steps-set-framework/

Happy Automation testing.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to understand the flow of application means which module should be automate then need to create folder structure
1- Create one properties file where every Object of pages will be store 
2- Create one base class that having the methods which will be use in other class that will inherits the property of base class such as browser opening, wait methods , read actions method 
3- create one class that will handle excel sheet means reading and writing excel contents 
4-Create one class for reporting that having method to take screen shot of failed test case and store in another folder 
5- crate pages as per module and final write test class that will responsible to automate or execute module

Always try to make your own framework don't copy other or follow other

Answer (score -2):

Check out the below link :-

http://www.evoketechnologies.com/blog/test-automation-framework-design/

Automation framework depends on the application requirement (type).
So I suggest you to understand the Application requirements first and then identify the framework
Pom if you have pages in your application without dynamic data.
Data Driven if you have dynamic data to be injected to script each time.
Keyword if you have the application with similar flow.
Hybrid if you have similar flow with Dynamic Data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply...Whatever you said are correct but I don't understand to organize the folders / packages and how to relate them i.e where to start and end the flow of script....